# How can I filter __in django ORM by records list?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I expect query like this:

```sql
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM mytable
WHERE (field1, field2) NOT IN(
    (1, 1), 
    (2, 2)
);
```

django==1.9.13

My current solution is:

```py
qs = MyTable.objects.all()
for (field1, field2) in data:  # List[Tuple[int, int]]
    qs = qs.exclude(field1=field1, field2=field2)
```

Comment: Honestly, your solution is not that bad since Django querysets are lazy and won't be executed until evaluated. It won't hit the database at each iteration of your for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve almost that exact SQL query using the ORM, if you really need to.

```
from django.db.models import Func, Field, Lookup    

class Tuple(Func):
    function = ''
    template = '(%(expressions)s)'

@Field.register_lookup
class NotIn(Lookup):
    lookup_name = 'not_in'

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
        params = lhs_params + rhs_params
        return '%s NOT IN %s' % (lhs, rhs), params

qs = (MyTable.objects.annotate(tup_fields=Tuple('field1', 'field2', output_field=Field()))
             .filter(tup_fields__not_in=data))
```

This will produce SQL like

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, (field1, field2) as tup_fields
FROM mytable
WHERE ((mytable.field1, mytable.field2) NOT IN ((1, 1), (2, 2)));
```

You can probably do without the `NotIn(Lookup)` class and do `.filter(~Q(tup_fields__in=data))`. which will generate a where clause like `NOT (field1, field2) IN (...)`.

You can also do it the way you are doing it, which may be just fine. The SQL generated is different, but the result is the same. I'm not sure if there are performance differences that are important to you or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can do it as

```
from django.db.models import Q

query = Q()

for (field1, field2) in data:  # List[Tuple[int, int]]
    query.add(Q(field1=field1, field2=field2), Q.OR)

qs = MyTable.objects.exclude(query)
```